# Ruby on Rails: how to make a form for associated models (nested)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, nested, models

First of all I have this:

https://polar-scrubland-30279.herokuapp.com/ - my project which is deployed on heroku (Captain Obvious)

I've got projects and todos inside them.
For this moment I show all projects using this way:

```
------index.html.erb------

<%= render @projects %>

------_project.html.erb-----

<div class="project">
  <div class="project-header">
    <h2><%= project.title %></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="project-todos">
    <% project.todos.all.each do |todo| %>
      <p><%= check_box('tag', todo.__id__, {class: 'icheckbox_square-blue', checked: todo.isCompleted}) %> <%= content_tag :todotext, todo.text %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And as you understand it doesn't allow me to change my todo's status when checkbox is checked. So that's why I need a form that will allow me to track all the checkboxes. Also I wanna make `text-decoration: line-through` when checkbox is pressed, but don't get how to.

Is there a way to creat a form which will satisfy my needs? Please can you help me, Any information will be appreciated.

**ADDITIONAL INFORAMTION:**

GitHub - https://github.com/NanoBreaker/taskmanager

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
end
```

todo.rb

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Comment: You're delving into the realm of javascript (client-side) luckily you don't need to leave ruby behind for lots of it!  Anytime you're looking to run code based on a user's actions before they submit a form etc. you'll want to use javascript (more importantly Jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the models:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :todos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :todos
end

class Todo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
end
```

[`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) lets you create or modify several nested `Todo` records at once when creating or updating a Project.

```
# will update 2 todos at once
@project.update(
 todos_attributes: [ { id: 1, isComplete: true }, { id: 2, isComplete: false }]
)
```

We can use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) to create nested inputs for todos:

```
<%= f.form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:todos) do |tf| %>
    <%= tf.check_box :isCompleted %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This generates fields for todos nested under the key `todos_attributes`. We can whitelist them by using a hash key containing a array of permitted attributes.

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @project = Project.new
    # this seeds the project with 3 empty tasks
    # otherwise we don't have any inputs.
    3.times { @project.todos.new }
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  def update
    if @project.update(project_params)
      # ...
    else
      # ...
    end
  end

  private 

  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project)
      .permit(:foo, :bar, 
        todos_attributes: [:isCompleted, :text]
      )
  end
end
```

You can create a form for each project by creating [a partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) which uses a [local](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) instead of an instance variable:

```
# app/views/projects/_form.html.erb
<%= f.form_for(local_assigns[:project] || @project) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for(:todos) do |tf| %>
    <%= tf.check_box :isCompleted %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

# app/views/projects/index.html.erb
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
  <%= render partial: 'projects/form', project: project %> 
<% end %>
```

You can reuse the same partial for the other views as well:

```
# app/views/projects/new.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'projects/form' %> 

# app/views/projects/edit.html.erb
<%= render partial: 'projects/form' %>
```

Comment: There are a few other issues with your app. Always use `snake_case` to name methods and columns. You're missing a foreign key constraint on `todos.projects_id`. Use the `belongs_to` macro when creating columns for belongs_to associations. You can fix it after the fact by creating a migration with `add_foreign_key :todos, :projects`.

Comment: got you bro! Thanks for the answer, gonna make everything work right now.

Comment: There are some misspells in your form as I understand, there should be 'tf`instead 't` and such method like `check_box_field`, so I used `check_box`. But this is form for just a single @project which is already defined, but how can I use for @projects? And one more question about migration, can I just add that string `add_foreign_key :todos, :projects` to my projects migration file?

Comment: You need a form for each project.

Comment: And one more question about migration, can I just add that string `add_foreign_key :todos, :projects` to my projects migration file? - Not really. That would require you to rollback the migration and re-run it which would be destructive. Once you have pushed a migration it should not be altered. Instead run `rails g migration AddProjectsIdForeignKeyToTodos`. Of course you can cheat with this if you are just creating an app for the sake of learning and have not set a production environment.

Comment: I fixed the typos in form as well.

Comment: I added a bit explaining how you would use partials to create forms for each project.

Comment: That's really cool dude, thanks for such a nice explanation! But I got few more questions, I hope you don't mind ^^

1. Code from `_form.html.erb` doesn't work  independently, it says `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`. So I just putted it into the cycle in `index.html.erb` instead `<%= render partial: . . . %>`. Controllers are fine.

2. Probably a silly question, but really what is the problem, `<%= f.text_field :title %>` this works inside my `form_for`, but why `<%= f.label :title %>` doesn't give me a project title? Also can't find a way to get todo.text.
`

Comment: `<%= f.label :title %>` gives you a `<label>`element that describes the input. If you want to print the title you would use `<%= f.object.title %>`

Comment: And yes the partial does work - you're doing something else wrong. But you may want to ask a new question as we are far beyond the scope of your original question.